# Force autoCompleteTextView dropdown to show in a different view

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

Usually the dropdown is visible as a dropdown with the autoCompleteTextView or you can anchor it to some other view.

What I need is to show the dropdown list as a listView below the autoCompleteTextView and not as a dropdown itself

something like this:

[image: Schreenshot]

So when I start typing "Ap", the only thing  that shows is Apps and no dropdown shows at all

Answer (score 1):

Auto Complete cannot do this but [you can use filters](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/).

A simple `TextView` (with a `TextWatcher`) and a `ListView` with a suitable adapter acting as a filter can achieve your goal. (Suggested by Nguyen Doan Tung)